# Retrieving rows from DB which contains same value in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Trying to retrieve rows which has same value(関西).

First I created a blade for this (kansai.blade) 
And then I set the route:

```
Route::get('/kansai', 'PagesController@kansai');
```

I set the controller:

```
public function kansai()
{

    $estates = allestates::where('region', '=', '関西')->get();

    return view('pages.kansai', compact('estates'));

}
```

After that gave the link in main.blade:

```
<li><a href="/pages/{{$estates->kansai}}"></a>関西</li>
```

But it returns with an error:

> Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   /var/www/html/laravel/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)

Do I missing something here? The problem is my controller I guess? 
Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: are you sure the $estates variable has some value? maybe the query returns no results

Comment: @FatemehMajd you can see the database here: https://imgur.com/a/DMbAjnA allestates has region column and I'm trying to retrieve rows which has 関西 in region column.

Comment: `allestates` is this the correct class name?

Comment: @Exterminator yes, table name is correct.  imgur.com/a/DMbAjnA I am retrieving data in kansai.blade. but I can't link kansai.blade in main.blade.

Comment: you send estates to kansai. But try use the variable in main.blade

Comment: do you have `kansai` column in your database table `allestates`?

Comment: show your `kansai.blade.php` and `welcome.blade.php`

Comment: @LeenaPatel I have region column in table. kansai is value in the region column. okay wait

Comment: ->get() returns collection not single item . so you can not access column directly . instead of get use ->first() witch return first item in result collection

Comment: Change `<li><a href="/pages/{{$estates->kansai}}"></a>関西</li>` to `<li><a href="/pages/{{$estates->region}}"></a>関西</li>`

Comment: does your array wrap in `estates`

Comment: Okay I solved the problem. Thank your for helping

Comment: @Potti can you share your model files code? whole code

Comment: @Exterminatorno need mate, I solved it. But really appreciate your helping. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

estates is an array not an object in this context. either loop trough it or specify an index.

Comment: i tried this and my link is gone :) `@foreach($estates as $estate)
              <li><a href="/pages/{{$estate->kansai}}"></a>関西</li>
              @endforeach`

Comment: why the compact in the controller tough? have you tried just passing the result?

Comment: and are you sure that the query actually has results? characters like these can be wierd edge cases with db queries sometimes (due to encpding and such)

Comment: yes has results I managed to see pages/kansai and data retrieving there. But in the main page I cant link. Also I used append for pagination. before That's why I compact it.         `return view("search", compact('estates', 'q'));`

Comment: what if the `$estates` is blank?

Comment: @Potti how did you solve it? People will may encounter the same problem and will look for a solution.

Comment: @cbaconnier thanks for the advice I shared it as a answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, it's likely my mistake actually. 
I already retrieved the data in kansai.blade. 
So I just the pass the link in main.blade

which is like below.

```
<li><a href="{{ url('/kansai') }}">関西</a></li>
```

and with this problem solved.